# How to use xor to swap a float and an uint number?

Tags: c#

I am trying to swap the 2 numbers using xor(^). This is what i wrote so far:

```
            float X = 5.5f;
            uint Y = 10123456;
            X = X ^ Y;
            Y = Y ^ X;
            X = X ^ Y;
```

Comment: You can't. xor is an *integer* operator. It doesn't apply to floating point numbers.

Comment: If this is for homework: You can't. Otherwise: You shouldn't waste your time with such a useless goal..

Comment: Compilers are written to notice tmp=x, x=y, y=tmp constructs and use faster methods than an xor swap, so although it was useful once upon a time, the xor swap is now mostly redundant.

Answer (score 3):

> How to use xor to swap a float and an uint number?

You Can't Do That™.

XOR is a bitwise operator. Using it on a floating point number requires a serious deep understanding of the way [IEEE-754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) is represented.

There was a time when programmers might have needed to know all this -- I once handled a requirement to convert IEEE float into DEC float and back -- but now there's hardware and fully-debugged runtime libraries for the purpose. Don't reinvent the flat tire.

Your task requires converting X to a `uint` and Y to a `float` as the values are swapped.

Answer (score 2):

Doing so requires interpreting the 32 bit floating point number as a 32 bit integer.
This typically involves [unsafe code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code) like so:

```
namespace XorSwap
{
    class Program
    {
        unsafe static void Main()
        {
            float X = 5.5f;
            uint* pX = (uint*) &X;
            uint Y = 10123456;
            *pX = *pX ^ Y;
            Y = Y ^ *pX;
            *pX = *pX ^ Y;
            Console.WriteLine($"X = {X}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Y = {Y}");
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(X - 1.41859833465e-38) < float.Epsilon); // 10123456 is 1.41859833465e-38 in IEEE 754 hex representation
            Console.WriteLine(Y == 0x40b00000); // 5.5f is 0x40b00000 in IEEE 754 hex represenatation
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is hardly useful. Compilers will notice a typical 3-step-swap operation and generate efficient assembly code. Make your code readable instead of applying premature optimization.

Comment: Yes, indeed, trust your compiler.

Comment: Since we are at it, what about an inlined assembly xor swap ?

Comment: @Soleil: inlined assembler in C#. Haven't seen that yet.

Comment: @ThomasWeller That's neat. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836120/using-c-inline-assembly-in-c-sharp