# ByteCode manipulation with ASM on .NET & C#

Tags: c#, cil, java-bytecode-asm

After using ASM on Java language, is there a faint way to use our byteCode manipulation module (insert some custom code) on .NET and C # platforms, through some sort of workaround? Anyway, we would choose Mono.Cecil, but we really fell in love with ASM. The obvious answer is no - for sure, but maybe there is some exciting solution?
All your answers are highly appreciated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your question appears to be "can I use a library that manipulates Java bytecode to somehow manipulate a completely different bytecode too", and the obvious answer to that is indeed no. An exciting solution would be translating Java bytecode on the fly to IL. That is in fact so exciting that I'm not aware of attempts at this that are practical and/or recent. Another exciting solution would be to port the library yourself, though obviously a 1-1 translation is impossible, as Java bytecode and IL share concepts but are quite different nonetheless. TANSTAAFL.

Comment: @JeroenMostert In theory, I thought to transcompile C# into Java, for example. But I'm pretty sure, that could be so heavy.. Thank you very much for answering my question!

Comment: Sound a bit like what AOP Tools for the NET Framework do (injecting code into the IL) . You may have a look at things like Postsharp https://www.postsharp.net/postsharp

Comment: I read the question as "run ASM in C# (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836120/using-c-inline-assembly-in-c-sharp) but it seems you want to just implement rewriting IL using assembly (instead of existing tools/code in high level languages) - it is unclear if it is the case. Note that purely entertainment-only projects are rarely fare well and this question feel like one. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Translating Java bytecode to IL code is exactly what the IKVM product did very successfully for many years, and still does so long as you don't want .NET Core support.

Comment: @george2020 SaxonCS is produced by transpiling SaxonJ, converting Java source code to C# source code. It wasn't easy, but it's quite possible. I wrote about it at Markup UK 2021 - https://markupuk.org/webhelp/index.html#ar04.html

Comment: @MichaelKay Congratulations on your achievement and thank you very much for your reply.